# how to Implement search functionality for custom listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have put searchbar in my app but I'm unable to make a search for the listview items...the edittext takes input but doesnt make the search.

here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class first extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText inputSearch;
private ListView listView;
private String[] names = {"प्रार्थना", "सुखकर्ता दु:खहर्ता", "गजानना श्रीगणराया", "येई हो विठ्ठले", "लवथवती विक्राळा", "दुर्गे दुर्घट भारी", "आरती ज्ञानराजा",
        "हे भोळ्या शंकरा", "ओवाळू", "मंगेशा महारूद्रा", "आला गणराया", "शेंदुर लाल चढायो", "एकदंता", "कर्पूर गौरा", "हे गजवधना", "प्रथमेश्वरा", "जयदेवा हे  साईनाथा",
        "श्री सत्यनारायणाची आरती", "श्री महालक्ष्मीची आरती", "ॐ जय लक्ष्मी माता", "आरती संतोषी माता की", "धन्य धन्य हो प्रदक्षिणा", "सुखंकर्ता की दु:खहर्ता",
        "ॐ जय जगदीश", "हे गौरी गजानन", "घालीन लोटांगण"};
private Integer imageid[] = {R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    final CustomList customList = new CustomList(this, names, imageid);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(customList);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), akalp.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 1) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Sukharta.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 2) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), gajananashriganraya.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), yehihovittale.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), lavathavthi.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), durgedurgat.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 6) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), nyanraja.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 7) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), bolya.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 8) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), vovalo.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 9) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), mangesha.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 10) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), alaganraya.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 11) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), shendorlal.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 12) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ekdanta.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 13) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), karpurgaura.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 14) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), heygajavadana.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 15) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), prathmeshvara.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 16) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), sainatha.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 17) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), satyanarayan.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 18) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), jaidevijaidevi.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 19) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),omjaimahalakshmi.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 20) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), maitohaarti.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 21) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), danyadanyaho.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 22) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), sukhartakidukharta.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 23) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), omjaijagdish.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 24) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), heygaurigajanana.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 25) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ghalinlotangan.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
 }
}
```

here's the code for CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private String[] names;
    private Integer[] imageid;
    private Activity context;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] names, Integer[] imageid) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_layout,names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.imageid = imageid;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null, true);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textViewName.setText(names[position]);
        image.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
        return listViewItem;
     }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual question you have?

Comment: Search for the listview items....

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This type of question is not proper to ask here because sounds like you are asking people to write code for you. You should try as much as you can then come with more specific question so people could help you to finish your task.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it does not make a search because you are not doing anything with the EditText. What you can do:

1. Set a "text changed" listener (EditText's addTextChangedListener() method) in OnCreate()
2. in onTextChanged() you can get the text that is on the input
3. update the data accordingly (e.g. names.contains() method)
4. supply the data to the ListView and call notifyDataSetChanged(). Or just re-create the list with the new data.